# Cannot setup multi-host Docker overlay network with etcd

Tags: linux, networking, docker, etcd

I am trying to connect two Docker hosts with an overlay network and am using `etcd` as a KV-store. etcd is running directly on the first host (not in a container). I finally managed to connect the Docker daemon of the first host to etcd but cannot manage to establish a connection the Docker daemon on the second host.

I downloaded etcd from  the [Github releases](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/releases/) page and followed the instructions under the "Linux" section.
After starting etcd, it is listening to the following ports:

```
etcdmain: listening for peers on http://localhost:2380
etcdmain: listening for peers on http://localhost:7001
etcdmain: listening for client requests on http://localhost:2379
etcdmain: listening for client requests on http://localhost:4001
```

And I started the Docker daemon on the first host (on which etcd is running as well) like this:

```
docker daemon --cluster-advertise eth1:2379 --cluster-store etcd://127.0.0.1:2379
```

After that, I could also create an overlay network with:

```
docker network create -d overlay <network name>
```

But I can't figure out how to start the daemon on the second host. No matter which values I tried for `--cluster-advertise` and `--cluster-store`, I keep getting the following error message:

```
discovery error: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
```

Both my hosts are using the `eth1` interface. The IP of host1 is `10.10.10.10` and the IP of host2 is `10.10.10.20`. I already ran `iperf` to make sure they can connect to each other.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured out how to connect the two hosts and to be honest, I don't understand why it took me so long to solve the problem. But in case other people run into the same problem I will post my solution here. As mentioned earlier, I downloaded etcd from the [Github release page](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/releases/) and extracted the `tar` file.

I followed the instructions from the [etcd documentation](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/clustering.md#static) and applied it to my situation. Instead of running etcd with all the options directly from the command line I created a simple bash script. This makes it a lot easier to adjust the options and rerun the command. Once you figured out the right options it would be handy to place them separately in a config file and run etcd as a service as explaind in [this tutorial](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/04/15/running-etcd-20-cluster/). So here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

./etcd --name infra0 \
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://10.10.10.10:2380 \
  --listen-peer-urls http://10.10.10.10:2380 \
  --listen-client-urls http://10.10.10.10:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --advertise-client-urls http://10.10.10.10:2379 \
  --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \
  --initial-cluster infra0=http://10.10.10.10:2380,infra1=http://10.10.10.20:2380 \
  --initial-cluster-state new
```

I placed this file in the `etcd-vX.X.X-linux-amd64` directory (that I just downloaded and extracted) which also contains the `etcd` binary. On the second host I did the same thing but changed the `--name` from `infra0` to `infra1` and adjusted the IP to that one the second host (`10.10.10.20`). The `--initial-cluster` option is not modified.

Then I executed the script on host1 first and then on host2. I'm not sure if the order matters, but in my case I got an error message when I did it the other way round.

To make sure your cluster is set up correctly you can run:

```
./etcdctl cluster-health
```

If the output looks similar to this (listing the two members) it should work.

```
member 357e60d488ae5ab3 is healthy: got healthy result from http://10.10.10.10:2379
member 590f234979b9a5ee is healthy: got healthy result from http://10.10.10.20:2379
```

If you want to be really sure, add a value to your store on host1 and retrieve it on host2:

```
host1$ ./etcdctl set myKey myValue
host2$ ./etcdctl get myKey
```

#### Setting up docker overlay network

In order to set up a docker overlay network I had to restart the Docker daemon with the `--cluster-store` and `--cluster-advertise` options. My solution is probably not the cleanest one but it works. So on both hosts first stopped the docker service and then restarted the daemon with the options:

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo /usr/bin/docker daemon --cluster-store=etcd://10.10.10.10:2379 --cluster-advertise=10.10.10.10:2379
```

Note that on host2 the IP addresses need to be adjusted. Then I created the overlay network like this on one of the hosts:

```
sudo docker network create -d overlay <network name>
```

If everything worked correctly, the overlay network can now be seen on the other host. Check with this command:

```
sudo docker network ls
```